# Information in text fields do not get retained objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, memory-leaks, subclassing

This is a simple program that takes two numbers inputed by the user in two separate text fields and adds them together when the 'Add' button is clicked. The way I have done this is by subclassing NSTextField into a class called MyTextField. I believe my error has something to do with memory leaks, but being an inexperienced programmer, I'm not quite sure how to deal with allocating and deallocating memory.

The problem is: When I click the Add button, it works perfectly. However, when I click it again, it does not show the correct amount. It keeps taking my inputs as nil and outputting 0. I have attached my code.

Note: I **know** that this is much more complicate than it needs to be! I am simply showing a simpler version of a much more complicated program that displays the exact same error.

MyTextField.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyTextField : NSTextField

@property (strong) NSString* number;
@property double dblNum;
-(id)initWithNumber:(NSString *)number;
-(NSString *)getNumber;
-(void)setNumber;
-(double)getDblNum;
-(void)setDblNum;
-(double)calcSum:(MyTextField *)other;
-(NSString *)description;
@end
```

MyTextField.m

```
#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

-(id)initWithNumber:(NSString *)number{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if ([number length] > 0){
            _number = number;
        }else{
            _number = @"0";
        }
        [self setDblNum];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)init {
    return [self initWithNumber:[self getNumber]];
}
-(NSString *)getNumber{
    return _number;
}
-(void)setNumber{
    _number = [self stringValue];
}
-(double)getDblNum{
    return _dblNum;
}
-(void)setDblNum{
    _dblNum = [_number doubleValue];
}
-(double)calcSum:(MyTextField *)other{
    return [self getDblNum] + [other getDblNum];
}
- (NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Number: %f", _dblNum];
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MyTextField.h"

@interface ViewController : NSViewController

@property (strong) IBOutlet MyTextField *valueOne;
@property (strong) IBOutlet MyTextField *valueTwo;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *answer;
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
}

- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {
    _valueOne = [[MyTextField alloc] initWithNumber:[_valueOne stringValue]];
    _valueTwo = [[MyTextField alloc] initWithNumber:[_valueTwo stringValue]];
    double ans = [_valueOne calcSum:_valueTwo];
    _answer.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ans];
}
@end
```

P.S. Sorry for the annoying amount of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `btnAdd:` is where the problem is.

```
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {
    _valueOne = [[MyTextField alloc] initWithNumber:[_valueOne stringValue]];
    _valueTwo = [[MyTextField alloc] initWithNumber:[_valueTwo stringValue]];
    double ans = [_valueOne calcSum:_valueTwo];
    _answer.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ans];
}
```

Each time the button is tapped, you're *recreating* both `MyTextField` instances. Instead, you simply need to get & set the values from your existing `valueOne` and `valueTwo` outlets, like:

```
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {
    double value1 = [_valueOne.text doubleValue];
    double value2 = [_valueTwo.text doubleValue];
    double ans = value1 + value2;
    _answer.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ans];
}
```

Obviously, you need to check the validity of the `valueOne` and `valueTwo` text strings.

You really don't need a `MyTextField` subclass, because it's not doing anything except converting strings to doubles (and vice versa).

Comment: Yes, but I needed to know how to avoid these problems while subclassing because my real project requires it. text is not a property on NSTextField so I had to change _valueOne.text to [_valueOne stringValue]. This worked though! Thanks so much! Also, does this mean that I don't need my constructor?

Comment: Crap; you're right about the `text` property; I was thinking of iOS `UITextField`s. But on your `NSTextField`, you can call `doubleValue` directly and skip having to deal with the string at all.

Comment: What specifically do you need to subclass `NSTextField` for?

Comment: My project is a time card so the textfields that the user enters numbers on are actually times and there are a couple things I need to do to manipulate the times and a couple variables I need to store...also attempting to use good programming practice

Comment: Ah, ok. So getting the fields' `stringValue`s is what you want, but I'm still not convinced that you need a subclass, especially because the conversion from string to double and the addition of the doubles is really business logic, and `NSTextView` handles the display. It's probably better to keep all the logic in your view controller, and use `NSTextField` without subclassing it.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I'm not certain. I'm trying to have as little in the ViewController as possible just so everything can be more organized. Is there any other way to do this? Maybe something along the lines of memory deallocation?

Comment: I really don't see how memory allocation has to do with any of this.